"org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException" while trying to run a spring project and using maven the dependency manager
Encountering this error while trying to create a local development environment for the application that i need to add some changes to, the application is based on java 11 so i'm using the oracle 11.0.21 jdk and maven 3.6.1, spring version is 2.2.0.
I have no idea why this issue is occurring and how to fix this, I have not made any code changes and the fresh checkout from git for the repo is working fine but were unable to find and reason that might be causing this on my system.
The complete error log is:
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.0.RELEASE)

{"Timestamp":"2024-04-01T10:32:27.155Z","SeverityText":"ERROR","Body":"Application run failed","msgparameters":null,"file.name":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","exception":{"exception.type":"org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException","exception.message":"Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup","exception.stacktrace":"org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup\n\tat org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:213)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:135)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createApplicationContext(SpringApplication.java:588)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)\n\tat com.pinelabs.merchant.MerchantPaymentDataServApp.main(MerchantPaymentDataServApp.java:32)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)\nCaused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:229)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.<init>(GenericApplicationContext.java:112)\n\tat org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext.<init>(GenericWebApplicationContext.java:81)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.<init>(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:115)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:72)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)\n\tat org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:200)\n\t... 12 more\nCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup\n\tat java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:594)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:92)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)\n\t... 22 more\n"},"thread.name":"main","service.name":"UNKNOWN","host":"PINEMAC0369.local","Env":"${sys:env}"}

The contents of my POM.xml are as follows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <!-- Build properties -->
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-boot.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <hibernate-core.version>5.4.29.Final</hibernate-core.version>
        <junit-version>4.12</junit-version>
        <openapi.version>1.6.8</openapi.version>

        <!-- Plugin versions -->
        <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.9.1.2184</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
        <formatter-maven-plugin.version>2.19.0</formatter-maven-plugin.version>
        <impsort-maven-plugin.version>1.7.0</impsort-maven-plugin.version>
        <autho.jwt.version>4.0.0</autho.jwt.version>
        <common-pinot-version>0.0.5</common-pinot-version>
        <identity.util.version>0.0.10</identity.util.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
             <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
             <version>${openapi.version}</version>
             <exclusions>
                   <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                   </exclusion>
             </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>com.networknt</groupId>
             <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
             <version>1.0.72</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-loader-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tngtech.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dataprovider</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>${autho.jwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pinelabs.identity</groupId>
            <artifactId>authUtil</artifactId>
            <version>${identity.util.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pinelabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>LoggingAPI</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pinelabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pinot</artifactId>
            <version>${common-pinot-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
             <artifactId>reactor-netty-http</artifactId>
             <version>1.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>com.pinelabs</groupId>
             <artifactId>http-client</artifactId>
             <version>0.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${sonar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.revelc.code.formatter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>formatter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${formatter-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.revelc.code</groupId>
                    <artifactId>impsort-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${impsort-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                        <version>8.29</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>validate</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                            <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                            <includeTestSourceDirectory>true
                            </includeTestSourceDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.revelc.code.formatter</groupId>
                <artifactId>formatter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>format</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.revelc.code</groupId>
                <artifactId>impsort-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${impsort-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <groups>java.,javax.,org.,com.</groups>
                    <staticGroups>java,*</staticGroups>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/thrift/*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <removeUnused>true</removeUnused>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>sort-imports</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sort</goal><!-- runs at process-sources phase by default -->
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

I am totally new to java, it'd be great to get some guidance.
I have tried using different SDKs for java 11 like openJDK, Amazon corretto 11 but faced the same issue, ideally it should be able to run on localhost.

If you are "totally new" to Java, it might be beneficial to start with a simpler Java project that does not involve Maven, Spring Boot, JPA, etc. Start small and once you have built an understanding add more complexity.

mixture of different Spring Boot Version 2.3.12.RELEASE and 2.2.0.RELEASE etc.

@knittl It is not in my hand to change my project, It is an existing project in which i have to a new change, I am working as an intern.

@khmarbaise I changed it and set the same version across the POM, this branch is working in other colleague's laptops, could there be any environment differences that can cause this? I also had a look at the constructor that is mentioned in the exception, looks fine to me and the class is also present in the package, but somehow it is not able to find it during runtime.
